# How to solve mesh error for narrow surfaces in Ansys Meshing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, ansys, cfd

I am simulating a spherical grooved bearing….e.g. A bearing that has spiral grooves on the ball. Please see the following figures.
There is a kind of lubricant between ball and cup, so as to prevent metal-to-metal contact (Full film lubrication theory). The dimension of groove and gap between ball and cup are in (mm) and (micron). For example, Value of groove depth is equal to 0.006 mm and also, areas of some surfaces are too small.

Fig1:

[image]

Fig2

[image]

Now in Ansys meshig, when I tried to mesh, I got following error(Fig 3,4,5,6). I want to mesh be structure.

Fig3

[image]

Fig4

[image]

Fig5

[image]

Fig6

[image]

According to the following Fig, I increase number of cell in edges and change dropped option to kept option in mesh method and the error is only as follows:

Fig7

[image]

In Fig5 is explained about narrow surface. What do these errors happen? I am grateful that guide me in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Scale it up to larger dimensions - the errors may be accumulating, you may need to consider geometric, kinematic and dynamic similarity...

Comment: It's not exactly clear how your model relates to the ball/socket problem you are trying to investigate.